# Fetch on-demand data from Azure Data Factory Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have searched for on-demand data fetch but found details about scheduling ADF pipeline.

I want to know about how to achieve on-demand data load from ADF pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for One-time pipelines is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-scheduling-and-execution#onetime-pipeline

You can use this for example with PowerShell (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-copy-activity-tutorial-using-powershell) to script one-time execution.